# TFS Build returning INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration, build-server

I've set up an automated build in TFS which both:

- Builds the project
- Runs the unit tests

However we are getting the following reported, with no pointers in the log:

[image]

All tests are succesfully ran, yet these errors appear to come from MSTest.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't see in the "Log", Try changing the Logging Verbosity (in Parameters tab when Queuing) up to Detailed / Diagnostic to see where about this is coming from?

Comment: Are the paths that you are using correct. Looks like it's trying to find something that doesnt exist.

Comment: @DaveShaw We've already tried both of these settings.  The line prior to these errors is relating to mstest.

Comment: What is the "Test assembly file specification" in your build definition?

Comment: It's `**\*test*.dll; **\*test*.appx` however this appears correct as all tests are ran (successfully)